# How to oAuth 2 different google accounts in an iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, oauth, google-signin

I have been following [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) link from google to start integrating Google Sign-In into my iOS app. I have a need to log into multiple Google, Office 365 and Salesforce accounts.

When I login with one Google account and then the only option I seem to have is to logout this account before I allow another login. What could I be missing and what should I do to allow logging in via multiple accounts simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact same problem while building my mail app.

Created a simple iOS framework to allow login to multiple google account through oauth. Hope it helps.
https://github.com/Thywis/MultiAccountOauth